# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'VarPhaseName' of undefined at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next]

Tags: angular

How to assign value of model class Array??

```
    export class Model{
          UserName : string
          FirstName : string
        }
```

Now I am Using this model in
            @Component({
            });

```
        export class demoCompoennt{
          model : Model[] = [];
          for(i=0;i<10;i++){
              this.model[i].Username = "Hello"+i;  //here I am got error like 
                                                   //Username not defined

        }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example on plunker or github.
It is hard to debug like this.

Comment: suppose I have model named model.ts export class{ username:string} and i used another class like export class {}

Comment: It looks like the code you have posted has nothing to do with the error message. Consider creating [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.